# Can one solve this system of qudratic equations unambigiously?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Given the parameters $p_1, p_2, p_3$ I want to know if the following system can be solved:

$p_1 a + p_2 c + ef = 0\\
p_1 b + cd + p_3 f = 0\\
ab + p_2 d + p_3 f = 0\\
p_1^2 +a^2+b^2=1\\
c^2+p_2^2+d^2=1\\
e^2+f^2+p_3^2=1\\
cf-p_2 e=b\\
ae-p_1 f=d\\
p_1 p_2 -ac=p_3\\
$

#### Background:

This system actually discribes a Rotation Matrix

$p_1\ \ a\ \ \ \ b\\
c\ \ \ \ p_2\ \ d\\
e\ \ \ \ f\ \ \ \ p_3$

where only $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ are know. For example $p_1=p_2=p_3=1$ would result in $a=b=c=d=e=f=0$.

I would like to know two things:

- Why is this system (unabigiously) solvable / not solvable?
- If it is solvable, what is the solution? (Less important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$M = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p_1 & a & b \\
c & p_2 & d \\
e & f & p_3 \end{array} \right).$$

If $M$ is a rotation matrix, then $M^{-1} = M^T.$ 
This implies that $M$ and $M^{-1}$ have the same entries on the main diagonal.
But if $M$ is not the identity, $M \ne M^{-1},$ so the rotation matrix is not
completely determined by the entries on its main diagonal.

On the other hand, 
if $[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]^T$ is a unit vector on the axis of rotation of $M$ 
and if $\theta$ is the angle of rotation about that axis, then
$$ p_i = (1 - \cos\theta) u_i^2 + \cos\theta \tag{1}$$
for $i = 1, 2, 3.$ Moreover, 
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1 + 2 \cos\theta.$$
Therefore we can express $\cos\theta$ in terms of $p_1,$ $p_2,$ and $p_3.$
Plug that value of $\cos\theta$ into equation $(1)$ for each $i;$
this either gives $u_1 = 0$ or gives two possible values of $u_1$
which differ only by a sign change.

We can safely assume that $0 \le \theta \le \pi,$ because the rotation described
by angle $-\theta$ and unit vector $[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]^T$
is the same as the rotation described 
by angle $\theta$ and unit vector $[{-u_1}\ {-u_2}\ {-u_3}]^T.$
That means that in general there are eight possible ways to fill in the matrix $M$
(one for each choice of the signs of each of the $u_i),$
therefore eight possible solutions to the given set of equations.
(For $0 < \theta < \pi,$ there are four solutions if exactly one of the $u_i$ is zero,
two solutions if two of the $u_i$ are equal to zero.
There are half as many solutions if $\theta = \pi,$ and of course
only one solution if $\theta = 0.)$
Moreover, by computing the rotation matrix for the rotation by angle $\theta$
around the axis given by $[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]^T,$
we can compute all the unknown entries $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$ in the rotation matrix
for a specific choice of  $[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]^T.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it can be solved. I need a case distinction. First assume that $p_1+p_2=0$. Then the system is obviously solved by $f=e=b=d=0$, $c=a$, and $a$ a solution of $a^2 + p_1^2 - 1=0$, i.e., with $a=\sqrt{1-p_1^2}$. In the second case we may assume that $p_1+p_2=1$ by rescaling. Then we may take $f=e$, and
$$
a= -\frac{1}{p_1}(e^2 - (p_1 - 1)c),
$$

$$
c=-\frac{1}{2e^2( 1- p_1)}(e^4 + 2e^2p_1 - e^2 - 2p_1 + 1);
$$
with $e\neq 0$ and $p_1\neq 1$, and $e$ satisfying a monic polynomial equation of degree $8$, which has a solution over the complex numbers, but is rather complicated. Also, the subcases $p_1=1$ and $e=0$ can be solved.

Comment: Are you sure that this captures all solutions? As far as I notice the last three restrictions, geometrically interpreted, say that those three vectors are orthogonal, which means that this system is actually symetrical in $p_1, p_2, p_3$

Comment: Give me a triple $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ where you think there is no solution.

Comment: The question is if there are any solutions that are not found using the formulas given in your answer (and implying that some of them can be found more easily than solving the degree 8 polynom)

Comment: I have found all solutions via Groebner bases, but the result is messy. You can try to find them "more easily" of course. I have only made a start for you.